# Declarative_authorization doesn't seem to load?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, declarative-authorization

I'm running bundler with rails 2.3.4.

I'm trying to get declarative_authorization to work (I added it to my Gemfile).

The error I'm getting is `undefined local variable or method 'filter_resource_access'`.

I'm guessing this means that declarative_authorization isn't loading? Since I'm using bundler I don't have a `config.gem` line for it in `environment.rb`. If I add it in, though, it throws an error trying to start the server: `Uninitialized constant Authorization`.

Not too sure what to do... Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you can use bundler with Rails 2.3.4 ? Follow the [excellent screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/188-declarative-authorization) to the T , and there is no reason why it won't work. Declarative Authroization is by far the most powerful authorization solution available.

Comment: i was pretty sure it worked with 2.3.4 but anyway i switched to 2.3.8 and it seems to be working fine :)

Comment: Hey, I have the same problem but I'm using 2.3.8. I'm also using bundler. Was there anything else you did Steven?